# Determine if task is earlier while only knowing if date is earlier and if time is earlier

Tags: java, date, object, time, logic

A class called **Time** contains a method `isEarlier(Time): boolean`, which returns `true` if the **Time** is earlier than the **Time** object passed as the argument, otherwise it returns `false`.

A second class called **Date** contains a similar method `isEarlier(Date): boolean`, which returns `true` if the **Date** is earlier than the **Date** object passed as the argument, otherwise it returns `false`.

A third class called **Task** has two data fields `Date date` and `Time time`. This class also contains a method called `isEarlier(Task): boolean`, which returns `true` if the **Task** is scheduled earlier than the **Task** passed as the argument. How can this method determine if the task is earlier by using only the `isEalier()` methods from the **Time** and Date **object**?

I don't think this is even possible without knowing if the dates are the same, which is impossible because the `isEarlier()` method only returns `true` or `false`. Am I right?

This is more of logic question than a language specific question.

```
public boolean isEarlier(Task argTask) {
    if (date.isEarlier(argTask.date)) {
        return true; // date is earlier
    } else if ("Is this possible without equality comparison here?")
        // date is the same, so we must also check the time
        return time.isEarlier(argTask.time);
    } else {
        return false; // date is later
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without equality comparison methods in your time classes, you will have to also do the reverse comparison using `isEarlier` to decide when to compare `time` fields.

```
public boolean isEarlier(Task argTask) {
    if(this.date.isEarlier(argTas.date)) {
        return true;
    } else if(argTask.date.isEarlier(this.date)) {
        return false;
    } else if(this.time.isEarlier(argTask.time)) { //reached if date fields are equal
        return true;
    }

    //At this stage, either `argTask.time.isEarlier(this.time)` returns true
    //or date and time in both objects are exactly equal
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you'd have to compare the times if the dates are the same but right now there is no way of knowing if that's the case.

If you want an else if-statement without an equality comparison, you could just fill in true but your else-statement would never be executed in that case.